# Access Keyboard Events in iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, events, iframe, dom-events

I have an `<iframe />` element on my HTML page and this frame is hosted on the same domain as the parent page.

Mouse events fire normally inside the frame, as they would normally do.

However, keyboard events do not fire at all, even when the frame is focused.

How to fire keyboard events (`onkeydown`, `onkeyup` and `onkeypress`) inside an `<iframe />`, hosted on the same domain as the parent window?

**Code I have tried (inside the iframe):**

```
window.onKeyUp = function() {
    alert("This alert never pops up.");
}

window.onKeyDown = function() {
    alert("This alert never pops up either.");
}

window.onMouseUp = function() {
    alert("This alert pops up whenever I click the mouse over the iframe!");
}

window.onMouseDown = function() {
    alert("This alert also pops up whenever I click the mouse over the iframe!");
}
```

Comment: can give some solution if you post the code u have tried..

Comment: @AshishPatel, okay, I've added some test code and the results of these.

Comment: *How to fire keyboard events?"* You want to dispatch them? Or is the wrong word being used in the question?